# Android intercept click iframe link - adbanner

Tags: android, iframe, webview, onclick, click

> I'm working to develop an app that will render some websites.
>
> I'm using webview to do it, but I had a big problem.
>
> I can't intercept click inside any iframe, for example accessing this
>   url: http://clikseguro.com/Search.aspx?q=android
>
> You will see a banner on left side, when I click on this banner using
>   any pc web browser they will open on a new tab or new window. But on
>   android I cant intercept this event and the page is loaded inside of
>   iframe.
>
> Is There anyway to get this click?
>
> This click don't call the shouldOverrideUrlLoading
>
> My WebView has WebViewClient and WebChromeClient.
>
> Thanks

**I Resolved IT.**

You just set:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

And override the

```
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView v, boolean d, boolean u, Message r)
```

So you can receive any click inside a iframe (link, img, e-mail)

Thanks

Comment: ... and how do you get the link that was accessed?